# Search feature in a website?

Tags: mysql, symfony, search, web

How do I implement search functionality in an e-commerce website using indexing feature. It's being build using the Symfony2 framework. What coding methods should I be using? Database being used is MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

There are various Free/Open source indexing Applications are available. Like:

1) [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)
2) [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
3) [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

You can use any of the above application to index the data, And you can use the Client Libraries/ APIs to search the contents.